# What is wrong with this getGeneratedKeys() JDBC statement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This code fragment

```
PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(
          query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
statement.executeUpdate(query);
try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    ...
}
```

keeps throwing

```
java.sql.SQLException: Generated keys not requested. You need to specify Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement().
```

I'd say that generatedkeys ARE requested at creation of the statement, but apparently I'm wrong. What is the issue here? (I'm new to JDBC. What I'm trying to do is retrieving the primary key value which has been automatically set (AUTO_INCREMENTed) during the preceding record insertion. Maybe there is a better way to do that... I'm using mysql.)

Comment: what database and what JDBC driver do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

don't pass the `query` parameter in use the no parameter version:

```
statement.executeUpdate();
```

The first version doesn't use the prepared statement you already made but instead makes a new one using your query String (without the RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS option)

Comment: Ok, this makes so much sense, thanks! (Could have thought of it myself...)

Comment: Technically it is also a bug in the MySQL driver, as this `execute` method (and its siblings that also take a String query) should throw an exception when invoked on an `PreparedStatement` and `CallableStatement` (this was added (or clarified) in JDBC 4.1).

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parameter from

```
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

change to

```
 statement.executeUpdate();
```

because you have already prepared the statement in

```
PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(
          query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Comment: Thanks! your answer is just as good, but I have to pick only one... Sorry :-)